# How can I pivot on the Y axis when rotating a game object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to make a rotation of a set angle across the pivot of a game object. This pivot is tilted and a bit skew. When I set the angle with the following code it rotates in according to the world Y axis, how can I make the rotation on the tilted gameobject pivot?

```
steer.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, new Vector3(0 ,1, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

To rotate an object around a pivot, use [Transform.RotateAround()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) method. So code would look something like:

```
Vector3 pivot = ...; // Object's pivot in world coordinates
float angle = ...; // You also want to multiply angle by Time.deltaTime

// To rotate around the world's up axis
steer.transform.RotateAround(pivot, Vector3.up, angle);

// To rotate around the object's up axis
steer.transform.RotateAround(pivot, steer.transform.up, angle);
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Vector3(0,1,0)` is "world space" up (same as Vector3.up btw). Easiest way to get to the "local space" up would be to use `transform.up`

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-up.html